# Virtualbox temporary macOS virtual machine

Tags: windows, boot, mac, virtualbox, virtual-machine

I know macOS virtualisation is not allowed on non-Apple made hardware but I really need to access encrypted data from my old MacBook backup that I can't open from Windows. Is there any way to install macOS on Virtualbox?

I've tried following steps from [here](https://intozoom.com/how-to-install-macos-ventura-on-virtualbox-on-windows-pc/) and I managed to boot the install image, initialize the disk and install the OS. As soon as the machine reboots though it reboots from the install image as the VM disk apparently has an empty EFI partition so the VM efi can't find anything to boot from.

Is there any workaroud? I've tried using opencore but I don't know how to use it and ended up just crashing the virtual machine. Does anyone know even a temporary solution?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: I think this might be off-topic here, and I'm not sure of as way to get macOS Ventura running in VirtualBox, but I was able to get macOS Big Sur up and running with this https://techsprobe.com/install-macos-big-sur-on-virtualbox-on-windows-pc/

Comment: @YisroelTech https://meta.superuser.com/a/12053/653259

Comment: Aside from the fact this is off-topic, one thing you really should be looking for is *the same macOS* that was on the old Mac. Time Machine format has changed over the years, so just trying to plonk Ventura on top of Windows will not necessarily solve your problem even should you succeed.

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because the use of macOS on non-Apple hardware is a legal grey area and as a result "Hackintosh" questions have been deemed [off-topic](http://meta.superuser.com/questions/1471/are-hackintosh-questions-allowed).